# What happens at a notary appointment?

Tags: canada, notaries

I'm having a document notarized in Ontario Canada for my university. This is my first notarization, and wonder what I may need to know for the appointment. I plan on bringing my ID, debit card, thats all. I expect to go in, have the notary attest that I understand what I am signing, then sign in their spot, and I sign in mine.

Is that all?

Comment: I would check on what form of payment is accepted. If notarizations are a sideline, and if the main business and the notary business must be kept separate, it's possible that cash payment is required, since being approved to accept debit cards involves some overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all.  A Notary verifies your identification.  There can be more than this, but that's generally all that happens.

Comment: Yes, it was very straightforward. They asked me to confirm I read what I was signing. Then walked me through signing it. That was all.